# move_uploaded_file no sube los archivos seleccionados

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Buen dia compañeros, tengo problemas al subir archivos, estoy haciendo pruebas en local, los datos se envian a la bbdd, genero la ruta de destino, pero a la hora de ejecutar la funcion move_uploaded_file no los sube, y no arroja ningun error.

El error me dice que la ruta destino no es un directorio, ya le di permisos al directorio padre.

```
$ruta_archivo = rutaBase.'documentos/otros';
$ruta_final = $ruta_archivo."/".$nombre_archivo;
if( is_dir($ruta_final) ){
            if( is_writable($ruta_final) ){
                if( move_uploaded_file($direccion_temporal, $ruta_final) ){
                    $respuesta['status'] = '1';
                    $respuesta['ruta'] = $ruta_final;
                    $respuesta['tmp'] = $direccion_temporal;
                }else{
                    $respuesta['status'] = '0';
                    $respuesta['ruta'] = $ruta_final;
                    $respuesta['tmp'] = $direccion_temporal;
                }
            }else{
                $respuesta['estado'] = 'la ruta no tiene permisos de escritura';
                $respuesta['status'] = '0';
            }
        }else{
            $respuesta['estado'] = 'la ruta no es directorio';
            $respuesta['status'] = '0';
            $respuesta['ruta'] = $ruta_final;
        }
```

Comment: Hola Hadik, sería genial si compartes el código con el ques estás haciendo para encontrar el error. Te recomiendo leer el [tour] y [ask]. Saludos

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Tu pregunta podría ser cerrada si no la mejoras. No es posible ayudarte si no indicas el fragmento de código problemático (no todo el programa) y explicas mejor el contexto en que se desenvuelve. Para ello puedes [editarla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/178458/edit). Siempre las preguntas se editan pulsando sobre la opción `editar` que aparece debajo de las mismas. Gracias.

Comment: Creo que estás cometiendo un error aquí: `if( is_dir($ruta_final) ){` porque lo que hay en la variable `$ruta_final` no es en sí la ruta donde debería ir el archivo, sino **el archivo en sí con todo y ruta** por eso, al preguntar si es un directorio te dice que no, porque no lo es... si lo cambias por: `if( is_dir($ruta_archivo) ){`  debería funcionar, a no ser que haya otro problema. Eso pasa cuando erramos en la *convención de nombres*, en vez de `$ruta_final` esa variable debió llamarse `$archivo` o `$archivoConRuta` o algo así.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que tú estás preguntando si el archivo es un directorio en tu lógica, aquí: <s>`if( is_dir($ruta_final) ){`</s>, porque lo que almacenaste en `$ruta_final` fue una referencia al archivo en sí: `$ruta_final = $ruta_archivo."/".$nombre_archivo;`.

Podríamos decir que has errado en la *convención de nombres*  y eso te ha llevado a una confusión en tu código.

Si cambias esto: `if( is_dir($ruta_final) ){` por esto: `if( is_dir($ruta_archivo) ){` debería funcionar.

Aquí te propongo esto, aplicando una *convención de nombres* más clara:

```
$ruta_archivo = rutaBase.'documentos/otros';
$el_archivo = $ruta_archivo."/".$nombre_archivo;
if( is_dir($ruta_archivo) ){
            if( is_writable($el_archivo) ){
                if( move_uploaded_file($direccion_temporal, $el_archivo) ){
                    $respuesta['status'] = '1';
                    $respuesta['ruta'] = $el_archivo;
                    $respuesta['tmp'] = $direccion_temporal;
                }else{
                    $respuesta['status'] = '0';
                    $respuesta['ruta'] = $el_archivo;
                    $respuesta['tmp'] = $direccion_temporal;
                }
            }else{
                $respuesta['estado'] = 'la ruta no tiene permisos de escritura'; //¿La ruta o el archivo?
                $respuesta['status'] = '0';
            }
        }else{
            $respuesta['estado'] = 'la ruta no es directorio';
            $respuesta['status'] = '0';
            $respuesta['ruta'] = $el_archivo;
        }
```

**PD**:

Hay otro elemento algo *confuso*  en la clave `ruta` del array `$respuesta`. Parece que esa clave referiría al archivo en sí, no a una ruta. Quizá conviene que la cambies también. El problema de la *convención de nombres* mal aplicada te lleva a ti mismo a confusiones y si otro programador lee tu código se le hace muy difícil de entender.

Comment: Si muchas gracias, ayer me di cuenta del error que estaba cometiendo y precisamente es lo que comentas, ya lo cambie y me esta funcionando bien... muchas gracias amigo

Comment: @HadikChivoChavez me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) en el Centro de Ayuda.